# shortcuts for SQL 2005 Query

Tags: sql-server-2005, keyboard-shortcuts

What are the different shortcuts for performing usual tasks in SQL 2005?

eg, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to show the result in text format, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> in data format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate:

[SQL Server Management Studio – tips for improving the TSQL coding process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101079/sql-server-management-studio-tips-for-improving-the-tsql-coding-process)

[“Favorites” or “macros” in SQL Server Management studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175944/favorites-or-macros-in-sql-server-management-studio)

MSDN articles listing all shortcuts:

[SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Keyboard Shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205(SQL.90).aspx)

[SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Keyboard Shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Highlight a table name in your query and as long as its in the same database <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> will show you schema information.  Very useful.